# How can I know a hash mined and confirmed by ethers.js

Tags: ethers.js

In ethers.js is there any way I can check whether a hash is mined and confirmed so that I know it is not reverted and valid?

Answer (score 8):

In order to know whether a transaction (transactionHash) has been mined and confirmed, the following steps are required:

1. Get the transaction receipt
2. Check whether the transaction has been included in a block i.e. the blockNumber is not null

Below is the code snippet for achieving this:

```
const isTransactionMined = async(transactionHash) => {
    const txReceipt = await provider.getTransactionReceipt(transactionHash);
    if (txReceipt && txReceipt.blockNumber) {
        return txReceipt;
    }
}
```

In this way you can check whether the transaction has been mined.

Comment: Close, but no banana. This does not take into account that `txReceipt` itself may be `null`. I just ran a version of this solution and ended up with `Cannot read property 'blockNumber' of null`.

Answer (score 2):

Now its:

```
    const txnCheck = async (txnHash) => {

        const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(ethereum);
        signer = provider.getSigner();
        let txn_test = await provider.getTransaction(txnHash);
        if (txn_test) {
            if (txn_test.blockNumber) {
                console.log("txn_test: ");
                console.log(txn_test);
                return txn_test
            }
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't fully answer the question -- how would you know if the transaction failed for some reason, or just hadn't completed yet?

Comment: Another way would be to scan the transaction receipt, and look for any events which are emitted only when a transaction succeeds. Thus, if such a topic is present in the events array of the transaction receipt, then the transaction has succeeded. This assumes an event is emitted though.